# why in case of electromagnetic waves, the value of 2 fields; electric and magnetic keeps changing? what causes the change?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am actually pretty bad at this topic. so can I get an easy explanation so that even a dumb person can understand!
all I know about this topic is that it has something to do with the interaction of both fields

Comment: So the Maxwell equations say that magnetic fields change when the nearby electric field twists around them, and electric fields in vacuum change in the opposite direction when the nearby magnetic field twists around them. Given this, there happen to be global solutions where the fields centered at position $\vec r$, time $t$, twist in just the right way so the same solution reappears at time $t+\Delta t$, but centered at some position $\vec r+\Delta\vec r$ where $\|\Delta\vec r/\Delta t\| = c,$ the speed of light. Could you specify where you're having trouble understanding these two facts?

Comment: What problems have you got, specifically with the explanations given on for example: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/emwavecon.html

Comment: Perhaps it is helpful for you to read  about what are [photons and EM radiation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon/253957#253957)